# Error while Adding Android Platform in Ionic framework in ubuntu

Tags: javascript, android, ubuntu, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

im trying to setup ionic framework for my ubuntu machine,i succeeded in initial process but got stuck in adding android platform.this is the error im getting

```
module.js:339
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'bplist-parser'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:337:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:287:25)
at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
at require (module.js:385:17)
at Object.<anonymous>    (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/cordova-common/src/ConfigChanges/ConfigFile.js:20:14)
at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
at require (module.js:385:17)
```

help me please

Comment: Is android up to date?

Comment: Try this https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/cordova-error-cannot-find-bplist-parser/38108/6

Comment: thanks it worked...http://www.ashif.me/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the same error. I fixed it by installing missing modules manually.

```
sudo npm install -g bplist-parser
sudo npm install -g minimatch
sudo npm install -g inherits
sudo npm install -g path-is-absolute
sudo npm install -g inflight
sudo npm install -g once
```

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error after updating cordova.
The solution I found was even easier:

```
﻿﻿sudo npm update -g
```

and that's all.
I hope it helps.